# Help connecting an Arduino and an electronic speed controller

Tags: motor

We have [this controller](http://www.servocity.com/html/precision_digital_speed_contro.html) that we are planning to use with [this motor](http://www.servocity.com/html/12_rpm_hd_precision_planetary_.html). How do we plug it to the Arduino to make it work?

This is a totally new subject for our school team, since we are mostly programmers, so your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to do a little more work than that.  We help people with design problem not assembly issues.

Comment: The operational connection will be trivial; what may be more challenging is if the controller is supposed to be programmed by moving transmitter sticks in a particular sequence.  You might need to have an alternate sketch which controls the PWM signal with a potentiometer to emulate that.

Answer (score 1):

HobbyKing, which sells Arduinos and is a great source for motors and controllers, has an instructable on this at http://www.instructables.com/id/ESC-Programming-on-Arduino-Hobbyking-ESC/

I found another on the OpenROV site, at http://community.openrov.com/forum/topics/how-do-i-activate-electric-speed-controller-with-arduino

Did you actually try googling "arduino electronic speed control" before coming here?

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please add some detail to your post that can help answer the question. You can quote text from the links.

Answer (score 0):

As the controller and motor are from the same vendor, they can help you with specific questions.

That motor controller is designed to emulate a servo motor. So it takes a servo-motor signal:
Ground
Power
PPM signal

The Arduino servo library will drive the PPM signal. Power and ground for the controller need to come from a separate power supply. The Arduino can't power it.